# React - How can I access a particular position in the array, and then change it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In state, I have an array and would like to access one of the array positions.
For example, in other languages it might be:

*usersJson[position] ...*

But in the react I can't do:

*this.state.usersJson[position] = ...*

Can anyone help?

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      usersJson: []
    };


//loads a list of users througth jsonPlaceholder data

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ usersJson: json }));
```

I have tried this:

```
{this.state.usersJson.map((item => {
      if (item.id === props.id) {
        return(
          item.email = props.email,
          item.address = {
            street: props.address.street,
            suite: props.address.suite,
            city: props.address.city,
            zipcode: props.address.zipcode,
          },
  item.phone = props.phone
)
}
     return null
    }))}
```

but I want something like

*this.setState({userJson[position]: ...})*

The array looks like:

```
usersJson:{
    id: ...,
    name: "...",
    email: "..",
    address: {
      street: "...",
      suite: "...",
      city: "...",
      zipcode: "..."
    },
    phone: "..."
  }
```

Comment: Where is your code which modifies an element?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I edit the question

Comment: I updated my answer to have more of a complete solution for you.

Comment: Can you confirm that usersJson is an object or an array of objects?

Comment: @JossClassey It's an array

Comment: Forget my answer then. It wasn't clear to me from your example if it was an array or an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy your array to a temporary array and then change that array. It would be something like

```
adjustArray = () => {
const {usersJson} = this.state;
let tempArray = [...usersJson];
tempArray[position] = "something";
this.setState = ({ usersJson: tempArray});
}
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot to use the spread operator, I will edit my post.

Comment: I didn't try it yet, but it's better do like you said or like `this.setState(prevState => { prevState.usersJson[0].email = props.email  })`

Comment: Well if you are only going to change one single thing you don't need to create a whole new array and change it, you can use the `prevState`. But if its the other way then you can use my solution. But I like mine because its easier to write :)

Comment: I need to change more things, I will try to use yours

Answer (score 1):

In React classes you should only update by using `this.setState`.

If you don't know what position of the array the `user` is in then you can use the `.find` method for arrays. However since you are trying to trying to access JSON, I recommend converting the array that you receive from the API into an object. Then you would be able to access the position with `this.state.usersJson[key]` where `key` is whatever you decide to name each object in `usersJson`.

Comment: I know the position, but if I put `console.log(this.state.usersJson[positon])`, it works but idk how I can do to have access to this postion with `this.setState`

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => { prevState.usersJson[position] })` Do whatever you need to with the value and be sure to return a new object! You can destructure `usersJson` from `prevState` if it's the only piece you need.

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => { prevState.usersJson[position] })`It is the same thing that create an object and replace the state?

Comment: if I do something like `this.setState(prevState => { prevState.usersJson[0].email = props.email })` It doesn't change the state

Comment: Because you didn't return a new object. The object returned becomes the new state not `prevState`. Return `{...prevState}`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

To update your state based on a property name:

```
state = {
    name : 'John',
    surname : 'Doe'
}

handleChange = (name, value) => this.setState(state =>({
    ...state,
    [name] : value
}))

render() {
    const { name } = this.state
    return <input value={name} onChange={e => this.handleChange('name', e.target.value))}
}
```